# What does 'for such actions as ...' mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Anyone can help to explain the meaning of **for such actions as ...** please? It's from the following context.

> Even when automatic archiving is enabled, you can use manual archiving for such actions as rearchiving an inactive group of filled redo log members to another location.

The upper text is from *Oracle documentation*. If it's too technical, please check the following example, which was found in *American Corpus*.

> Last year, the company unveiled the Jawbone Icon as the first Bluetooth headset with downloadable apps for such actions as voice dialing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence has swapped the words around. Although this is still correct, it is a little confusing. Think of it as "for actions such as" or "for actions like":

> ... you can use manual archiving for actions such as rearchiving...
>   ... you can use manual archiving for actions like rearchiving.

That might make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks **Thursagen**, you answered a lot of my questions.

Comment: Your use of "swapped" suggests that the order in the example is abnormal, but it isn't. I would say the phrase "such _nouns_ as" is just as common as the phrase "such as".

Comment: @Yousui: I agree with Colin: *such actions as* is perfectly normal and common. In fact, it is probably stylistically preferable in most cases.

Comment: @Colin, note that I say it is correct, but can be confusing, like in this case, where Yousui has been confused a little

Comment: @Thursagen: Okay, but I still don't think it is confusing at all to native speakers.